# Azure Data Factory V2 Copy Activity is not cleaning/deleting staged files/containers after copying data to the destination (Like: Snowflake)

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

Azure Data Factory V2 Copy Activity is not cleaning/deleting staged files/containers after copying data to the destination (Like: Snowflake).

Is this a bug? In my ADF, the container level is set for the staging area and I end up with multiple GUID containers. Some containers are even having metadata files.

According to Microsoft, all the temporary files/folders/containers created by Azure Data Factory in the Staging Area should be automatically deleted by the ADF after the Copy is successful.

Please guide.

Comment: What are your source and sink types and their configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to Microsoft, all the temporary files/folders/containers created by Azure Data Factory in the Staging Area should be automatically deleted by the ADF after the Copy is successful.

**For stagging we have 2 options for linked service:**

1. Azure Blob Storage.
2. Azure Data Lake Service.

- **Azure Blob Storage.**
  -- If you selected Blob storage for staging it will delete or cleanup all folders which are created at the time of staging.
  -- As blob storage can't keep empty folders in it.

**Blob storage After stagging:**
[image]

- **Azure Data Lake Service.**
  -- If you selected ADLS for staging it will just delete or cleanup the data file which is created at the time of staging.
  -- As you can keep empty folders in an ADLS.

**ADLS After stagging:**
[image]

**Container is not get deleted in either of the storage accounts.**